# (Swift) 'use of unresolved identifier 'FIRStorage'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase and I have the following line of code:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
```

which gives me the error 'use of unresolved identifier 'FIRStorage'.

These are my imports in my file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
```

In the video tutorial I am following the person in the video only has these two imports and gets no error. 'FIRStorage' also seems to be an actual class in the Firebase documentation. Is there an import I am missing? Is there something wrong with my frameworks or podfile?

Here are my pods:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `import FirebaseStorage`

Comment: Add Firebase/Storage to your podfile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need install FirebaseStorage to use it

Follow this instruction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start

Answer (score 3):

You need to the following steps:

1. import FirebaseStorage
2. FIRStorage has been renamed to Storage

Hopefully you find it helpful.